# Same footer/sidebar in wordpress multisite

Tags: footer, wordpress

Wondering if it is possible to use same footer file for main site and the sub sites in a wordpress multisite setup.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for multisites using different themes

Comment: no, you have to make a unique one for each theme. or you can simply make one php file and call it where you want